# Regex to extract numbers from a String in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

How can I extract the numbers from col A and print in into col B.

I am using the below regex function, it print all the numbers with a space between them.

How can I get the initial set of numbers and skip the remaining ones.

Docetaxel Injection 160MG/16ML prints  **160 16**. I need to print only **160**.

```
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

    For Each C In Myrange
        strPattern = "\D+"

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = C.Value
            strReplace = "$1"

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                C.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, " ")
            Else
                C.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using Regex, can you just search for a space, and use =left?

Comment: But can I extract just the numbers without using regex?

Comment: Probably not - I was under the impression from the example you gave that your data is just numbers morenumbers - is this incorrect?

Comment: With the regex function it is extracting just numbers. E.g. Docetaxel Injection 160MG/16ML prints 160 16. I am trying to print just the digits before the space, like just 160 and not 160 16 in the new column

Comment: Is it always 3 digits?

Comment: I used .Execute instead of .Replace in my code and worked to give me only the first set of numbers from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (pattern allows for decimals but not very robustly so):

```
Sub splitUpRegexPattern()

    Dim re As Object, c As Range
    Dim allMatches

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "([\d+\.]+)"
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Global = True

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10").Cells
        Set allMatches = re.Execute(c.Value)
        If allMatches.Count > 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = allMatches(0)
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "(Not matched)"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This solution does not print the numbers, everything except the numbers, like PRECEDEX 200 mcg 2 mL FTV will get printed as PRECEDEX   mcg   mL FTV

Comment: So what you're saying is you didn't even try it?

Comment: Below is what I did to print just the first set `If regEx.test(strInput) Then
                C.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Exceute(strInput)(0)
            Else
                C.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
            End If `

Comment: Yes, it stops when it finds the first " . " like in Docetaxel I.V. Infusion 120mg/12mL Hospira it prints . and not 120

Comment: You can just remove the `\.` if you don't care about decimals.  Or find a more-robust pattern...

Answer (score 1):

*If its always 3 digits then use `\s\d{3}`* *https://regex101.com/r/lEc4mN/1*

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Matches As Variant

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

    For Each C In Myrange
        strPattern = "\s\d{3}"

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
                 Set Matches = .Execute(C.Value)
            End With

            If Matches.Count > 0 Then
                Debug.Print Matches(0)
                C.Offset(0, 1) = Matches(0)
            Else
                C.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
                Debug.Print "Not Found "
            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to extract the first set of numbers till the space. PRECEDEX 200 mcg 2 mL FTV should print only 200 and not 200 2.

Comment: @user9230639 it should work- also try to `C.Offset(0, 1) = Trim(Matches(0))`